# how can i solve python threading problem when getting error message Exception in thread Thread-1:

Tags: python, multithreading, server, client

so I'm trying to create a server and client system that takes in inputs from the clients and displays it on the server-side , but I'm running into an issue that I can only send 1 input signal per client and then I get

```
  File "client.py", line 25, in <module>
    send(input())
  File "client.py", line 20, in send
    client.send(message)
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

and on the server side i get the following message when sending an input message

```
[STARTING] server is starting ...
[LISTENING] server is listening on 127.0.1.1
[NEW CONNECTION] ('127.0.0.1', 60468) connected.
[active connections] 1
[('127.0.0.1', 60468)] hello
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "server.py", line 21, in handle_client
    msg_length = connection.recv(HEADER).decode(FORMAT)
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

the server file

```py
import socket
import threading

PORT = 5054
HEADER = 64
SERVER = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
ADDRESS = (SERVER, PORT)
FORMAT = 'utf-8'
DISCONNECT_MSG= "DISCONNECT"

serv = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
serv.bind(ADDRESS)



def handle_client(connection,addr):
    print(f"[NEW CONNECTION] {addr} connected.")

    connected = True
    while connected:
        msg_length = connection.recv(HEADER).decode(FORMAT)
        if msg_length :

            msg_length = int(msg_length)
            msg = connection.recv(msg_length).decode(FORMAT)
            if msg == DISCONNECT_MSG:
                connected = False
            print(f"[{addr}] {msg}")

        connection.close()


def start():
    serv.listen()
    print(f"[LISTENING] server is listening on {SERVER}")
    while True:
        connection,addr = serv.accept()
        thread = threading.Thread(target=handle_client, args=(connection,addr))
        thread.start()
        print(f"[active connections] {threading.active_count()-1}")


print("[STARTING] server is starting ...")
start()
```

and the client file is

```py
import socket

PORT = 5054
HEADER = 64
SERVER = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
ADDRESS = (SERVER, PORT)
FORMAT = 'utf-8'
DISCONNECT_MSG= "DISCONNECT"

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect(ADDRESS)

def send(msg):
    message = msg.encode(FORMAT)
    msg_length = len (message)
    send_length = str(msg_length).encode(FORMAT)
    send_length += b' ' * (HEADER - len(send_length))
    client.send(send_length)
    client.send(message)



while True:
    send(input())
```